# Joining tables in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table...

```
col1  | id   | col3|
---------------------
 1    |123   |     |
 2    |456   |     |
 3    |789   |     |
```

And I have another table...

```
id  | name |
------------
123 | Tom  |
456 | Kate |
789 | Pork |
101 |Winter|
102 |Roll  |
```

I want to join the tables together to get a result that looks like this...

```
col1  | id   | col3| name
----------------------------
 1    |123   |     | Tom
 2    |456   |     | Kate
 3    |789   |     | Pork
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the data where id from one table matches to id at another table then you can do an inner join like this:

**SELECT *
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id**

If you want all the data from the first table but only matched id data from the second table then you can do this:

**SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id**

For more information about Joins you an refer to this link - [SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

use inner join between two tables

```
select col1,table1.id,col3,name from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id =table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id;
```